# Cannot view exceptions thrown during Tomcat startup from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse to debug a web application through a local installation of Tomcat.

When I start the Tomcat server through Eclipse and watch the `catalina.out` as the WAR file is unpacked, the Eclipse debugger will suspend and jump to a `NoClassDefFoundError` in the bootstrap thread multiple times (5-6) during startup. The only reason it's doing this is because I have explicitly set breakpoints on instances of `NoClassDefFoundError`. The application deploys and runs as expected, but I still want to know what is going on with the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

`catalina.out` doesn't show anything about these exceptions and I can't find any information about what's causing this other than the fact that the breakpoints are being hit.

Anyone know how I can tell Eclipse to show me the specific of the exception being thrown? I have the stack trace, but it's not very helpful since I don't have the source attached for the libraries that it's occurring in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can see more details if you modify the loggin level. If you use the default Tomcat without custom modifications, then edit the file `${catalina.base}/conf/logging.properties` and replace with FINEST in several lines:

```
org.apache.catalina.level=FINEST
```

In your application, add the file `WEB-INF/classes/logging.properties`

For more details about that, see http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: Then change the default loggin to log4j. Follow the instructions.

Comment: Several log in Tomcat appends to files. For log4j and if you want to see in Console View in eclipse use ConsoleAppender

Comment: This didn't solve the immediate problem, but it helped me learn about log levels and log4j.