# Mystery exceptions during Tomcat startup from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, tomcat, logging

Related: [Cannot view exceptions thrown during Tomcat startup from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10387940/cannot-view-exceptions-thrown-during-tomcat-startup-from-eclipse)

I have Eclipse setup to force break on `NoClassDefError` exceptions. When I start tomcat through Eclipse and my web app is deployed, I get 5-6 forced breaks on this exception type, but literally nothing is output to catalina.out nor my log4j log file. I've tried several different log levels for log4j (error, warn, debug) but I can't find any information about these exceptions occurring. In fact, the only reason I know they're happening is because the Eclipse debugger is breaking on them.

Conceptually, I understand what the `NoClassDefError` exception is indicating, but I can't obtain which class is failing to load because I can't find the stack trace anywhere!

Comment: Tomcat may just scan for certain (optional) libraries? Does this happen with and without your application (war) deployed to the server?

Comment: Good idea, I've tried to start without my application deployed and the errors are still thrown. It appears that these exceptions aren't related to my application. I just wish I knew what Tomcat was looking for.

Comment: If the Eclipse debugger is breaking on the exceptions, doesn't it show the name of the requested class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did figure this one out. I just ignored the exceptions and everything seems OK. When I get more time, I'll dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have write permissions on the Tomcat log folder?

Also, make sure all your libraries will end up in your War.
Left click on your project, go to Properties.
Go to deployment assembly.
Make sure all your libraries goto `/WEB-INF/lib` folder in the war that will be created.

Comment: The log files are written properly, there's just no mentions of these exceptions in the logs. I don't have a Deployment Assembly section under the Properties window.

Comment: Is your project a Dynamic Web Project? If the answer is no, you can convert it using the section Project Facets in properties.

Comment: I'm willing to do the conversion, but I'm worried that it will break something (I worry a lot). This is code that I've inherited.

Comment: You can create a copy of the entire workspace folder, then switch workspace to the new folder and make the conversion.

Comment: I'll check it out for curiosity's sake, but I've recently discovered that these exceptions may not be related to my application.